# TSQL increment value based on month(date)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that selects the month (date) for `dateadd(month, 3, getdate())`. Sorry I'm writing this in pseudocode. It gets the month of the next 3 months. I need to assign another field to say month1, month2, month3 regardless of what the actual month value is.

Could someone please tell me a simple way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Please include sample data and the expected output.  Any answer based on what you have included would only be a guess.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, perhaps you may have to use `dateadd(month,3,getdate())`. Sample data and expected result will help us understand better

Comment: The terms "month" and "date" (in your first sentence) are inconsistent. Perhaps now you might realize that writing requirements (or even good technical documentation) is difficult. Given a datetime value (e.g., that returned by getdate), what value or set of values do you expect as a result? Note that "month" can be represented as a number, a name (in a particular language), or an abbreviation.

Comment: @marc_s https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/332043

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear; but on the off chance I've understood correctly...

```
SELECT Month(DateAdd(month, 1, GetUtcDate())) AS month1
     , Month(DateAdd(month, 2, GetUtcDate())) AS month2
     , Month(DateAdd(month, 3, GetUtcDate())) AS month3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a pivot query as follows:

select * from
  (
  SELECT

```
wl.partnumber 
,isnull(sum(wl.QORDER),0) as qty_usage
,datename(month, ws.start_DATE)  AS MonthUsed
,month(ws.start_date) as MonthDate

from wo_hdr
join wo_line wl on wo_hdr.DOC_NO = wl.DOC_NO
join [WO_HDR_STATUS] ws on ws.PARENT_DOC_NO = wl.DOC_NO
join CUSTVEND c on c.acctno = wl.ACCTNO 
 where 1=1 

and wl.PARTNUMBER = @partnumber
and ws.START_DATE between dateadd(year,-2,getdate()) and dateadd(year, -2,dateadd(month,3.5, getdate()))
group by wl.partnumber, datename(month, ws.start_DATE) ,month(ws.start_date)
```

)
        DataTable PIVOT (avg(qty_usage) FOR
          [MonthUsed] IN ( [January], [February], [March], [April], [May], [June], [July], [August], 
    [September], [October], [November], [December])) pivottable

Output results in gridview.